# php app deployed to GAE successfully, but cannot run it

Tags: php, google-app-engine, deployment

I have a php app which runs perfect on localhost:8080 using GAE launcher. Then I deployed it to the GAE successfully. But I cannot run it after deployment. The warning in the log is:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Function not implemented in Unknown on line     
0
```

I don't know why this happens because the app runs perfect on the localhost. 
The url of this app is: http://yapigtest.appspot.com/

Thanks!

Comment: probably need a code snippet to help diagnose.

Comment: so it is the code problem? But if so, why it is ok for running at the localhost?

Comment: could be any number of reasons - not worth speculating without knowing what's failing.

Comment: I used the code yapig-0.95b download from yapig website. It is a sample gallery to upload photos and to create galleries. There are quite a lot of codes so I don't know what should be displayed here. But in the GAE log, there is another error: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404. So is it because of the photo problems? Thanks.

Comment: Appengine is returning a 404 (page not found) error when I go to the url provided. The most likely cause of this would be not having a handler configured for the default url. What do you have in your app.yaml file?

Comment: Thanks@IanGSY Yes, I forgot to set a handler for the default url. Now it's solved.

Comment: looks like it's not a great idea to use yapig-0.95b (http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-3094/product_id-5438/version_id-25376/Yapig-Yapig-0.95b.html)